# R: fromJSON dynamic keying

Tags: r, json

I have a JSON file with information on birds.  It looks a bit like this:

```
{
  "Cardinal":{
    "Wingspans":[22.9,21.2,23.4],
    "Sightings":["Stream","Scramble","Stream"],
    "Gender":["M","F","M"],
    ...
  },
  "Bluejay":{...},
  ...
}
```

In my app, I use a selectInput to allow users to pick between different types of bird (Cardinal, Bluejay, Junco, etc), and update the data.  I've successfully hardcoded the keying for any given single case, for example:

```r
    savedData <<- fromJSON(file = "birds.json")
    wingspans <<- data.frame(savedData$Cardinal$Wingspans)
    sightings <<- data.frame(savedData$Cardinal$Sightings)
```

And so on.  **What I would like is for the "Cardinal" part to instead use the selectInput Id "typeSelect" so that when the app goes to load the data, it uses whichever bird the user has specified from the drop down menu.**  Here are some bad ideas which did not solve the problem:

```r
    wingspans <<- data.frame(paste0("savedData$",input$typeSelect,"$Wingspans"))
    wingspans <<- data.frame(savedData$(input$typeSelect)$Wingspans)
    wingspans <<- data.frame(savedData$input$typeSelect$Wingspans)
```

These all either produced syntax errors, or just gave me a 1x1 data frame with the pasted path name as the cell value.  Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an object value, so use `[[` instead of `$` as `$` will literally evaluate

```
wingspans <- data.frame(savedData[[input$typeSelect]]$Wingspans)
```

Or can have all the extractions with `[[`

```
wingspans <- data.frame(savedData[[input$typeSelect]][["Wingspans"]])
```

---

Or if we have `purrr` loaded, `pluck` may be useful as well

```
library(purrr)
wingspans <- data.frame(pluck(savedData, input$typeSelect, "Wingspans"))
```

Comment: Hrmm... the first two are creating a data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows.

EDIT: Wait, I think I capitalized the selectInput, but not the key names in the json file.  One sec.

EDIT 2: Yes, the first two things work.  Thank you very much!

Comment: The `typeSelect` should match the id value you provided in the ui.  Or else, it could return NULL

Comment: Yep, that was the problem.  typeSelect had "Cardinal", whereas the key in the json file was "cardinal".  Thank you very much!

Comment: @DavidRobie `R` is case sensitive.  So, it needs exact matche.  Although with `$`, there is partial matching, it is still not case matching